# How can I configure load balanceing multiple SharePoint2010 web server using Network Load Balancing?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

How can I configure load balanceing multiple SharePoint2010 web server using Network Load Balancing ? I googoled and binged , not much resources could be found on SharePoint2010.Can anyone point me to some useful resouces?I am pretty new to the IT Pro side of SharePoint , any general guidelines would also be useful.

Answer (score 1):

In the past I have used [this guide](http://www.combined-knowledge.com/Downloads/2007/How%20to%20scale%20out%20a%20SharePoint%20farm%20and%20configure%20IIS%207%20Microsoft%20Network%20Load%20Balancing%20on%20windows%20server%202008.pdf) published by Combined-Knowledge, written by Steve Smith.

Answer (score 0):

follow the folllowing posts

http://www.harbar.net/articles/spca.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754833(WS.10).aspx